# Searching for Test Contributions

Tags: search, testing

I have just started making contributions in Test mode. I understand that "Test contributions are not visible on the Contributions tab, but can be viewed by searching for 'Test Contributions' in the CiviContribute search form", but I don't know how to filter that Find Contribution form to generate the test results. Eg. When I search for contributions made this year the test contributions I made today aren't returned. Am I using the wrong search form?

Comment: You haven't said if you've checked the box that says "Contribution is a Test? Yes No ". It's about half-way down on the left on the find contributions form (Contributions -> Find Contributions).

Comment: I searched and scrolled but I didn't see that "Contribution is a Test" button in plain sight. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Demerit. I used the box that says "Contribution is a Test? Yes No ". It's about half-way down on the left on the find contributions form (Contributions -> Find Contributions).